# Applying for a UK visitor visa in India after receiving a UK visa refusal in Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

With regard to my visa refusal as mentioned in my previous post, I have tried to change my residence status from being under the sponsorship of my father to my current employer. But due to certain bureaucratic hassles this process is going to take a lot of time and is going to further delay my new visa application.
So I am currently thinking of reapplying from India which is my native country, as such I am wondering about how it will affect my chances of getting a visitor visa since most of my documents like bank statements, salary letter are being issued from Saudi Arabia.
Would these documents be still valid for visa application in India? Would I be needed to submit bank statements for my accounts in India and would I need to show my residence permit of Saudi Arabia?
As such would the previous queries being raised in Saudi Arabia regarding my visa refusal be still valid and be used as reference while assessing my new visa application ?

Comment: This strategy will ultimately make things worse because nothing at all will sync up.   Finish regularising and then apply from Saudi Arabia.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for a UK visit visa in any country that has a British mission with a visa issuing post AND where you are not in breach at the time of your application.  In your case we have to take account of your [previous refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50564/uk-visitor-visa-refusal) in which the ECO pointed out that your status in Saudi Arabia is possibly imperilled and questioned its validity.  Your application contained no explanation for why you had not regularised and it should have.

This leaves you with two alternatives...

1. Regularise your status in Saudi Arabia and make a fresh application
   at the British mission there citing change of circumstances; or
2. Go to a place where your status is regularised (in your case, India)
   and apply there (also citing change of circumstances).

At face value the first option is better because there is less to explain and you will have fully addressed the reasons for your prior refusal.  The second option leaves the possibility for the ECO to conclude that he was right and you are not a bona fide applicant.  Moreover if you return to India you have the problems of establishing yourself there as 'plugged in' to the economy, which will take you a while to accomplish.

**As such would the previous queries being raised in Saudi Arabia regarding my visa refusal be still valid and be used as reference while assessing my new visa application?**

Yes they would. Not only that, but they would also raise new doubts about your circumstances.  But as mentioned, you can apply wherever you want.

NOTE: I looked at [UK Standard Visitor Visa refusal due to lack of proof of employment and accommodation. What are my options?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50564/uk-visitor-visa-refusal) again and concluded that the answer there *still stands*.  They are not going to be happy until you either regularise or explain why you have not regularised.

Comment: I am now planning to apply for tier2 visa . I couldn't regularize till now . I am planing to explain it with support of documents . Hope it works.